# Python Dataframe: Calculating Confidence or Prediction Intervals Using Groupby on One Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, intervals

I have a table like below:

```
Type    Actual  Predicted
A       4       3
A       10      18
A       13      11
B       3       10
B       4       2
B       8       33
C       20      17
C       40      33
C       87      80
C       32      30
```

I wanted to calculate the R^2 and RMSE for each Type.  The code to do that is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error

def r2_rmse( g ):
    r2 = r2_score( g['Actual'], g['Predicted'] )
    rmse = np.sqrt( mean_squared_error( g['Actual'], g['Predicted'] ) )
    return pd.Series( dict(  r2 = r2, rmse = rmse ) )

your_df.groupby( 'Type' ).apply( r2_rmse ).reset_index()
```

Sample Output Table (values are hypothetical):

```
Type    R^2     RMSE    
A       0.66    4   
B       1.00    6   
C       0.03    1
```

The above code worked and gave me the output I wanted.  But now I want to add confidence / prediction intervals into the table at the Type level.  I have literally scoured the internet on how to do this with no luck.

Conceptual Question: If I want the range of values in which the Actual value is captured with 95% confidence, do I run the confidence interval on the Actual column or the Predicted column?

Below is the sample table I want:

```
Type    Conf_Int_90%  Conf_Int_80%
    A    (21, 100)       (5, 55)
    B    (10, 46)        (3, 14)
    C    (1, 19)         (12, 19)
```

I have a sense that the confidence interval code is something like this:

```
st.t.interval(0.95, len(a)-1, loc=np.mean(a), scale=st.sem(a)) BUT ...
```

What specific code do I incorporate into my existing code (shown above) so I get the table output I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following, and from my understanding, the confidence interval should be operated in the predicted columns. Hope it helps you :)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error

def r2_rmse_interval(g):
    r2 = r2_score( g['Actual'], g['Predicted'] )
    rmse = np.sqrt( mean_squared_error( g['Actual'], g['Predicted'] ))
    st_interval = st.t.interval(0.95, len(g) -1, loc=np.mean(g.Predicted), scale=st.sem(g.Predicted))
    return pd.Series( dict(  r2 = r2, rmse = rmse, st_interval = st_interval) )


df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
               'Actual': [4, 10, 13, 3, 4, 8, 20, 40, 87, 32],
               'Predicted': [3, 18, 11, 10, 2, 33, 17, 33, 80, 30]}, 
                columns=['Type', 'Actual', 'Predicted'])

df.groupby( 'Type' ).apply( r2_rmse_interval ).reset_index()
```

Comment: unfortunately all my values are coming out as (nan, nan) for st_interval

Comment: hi, may I know how you tried above code? I have tested it, and it can return the result as you want.

Comment: I got it!  Error on my side ... it worked thank you so much

Comment: is it okay for me to run the CI on the actual field?  The reason is my predicted values were given to me and every "predicted" value for the same Type is the same value

Comment: hi, as my understanding, the CI works on predicted value. but if you want to return values on actual, just change code to:  st_interval = st.t.interval(0.95, len(g) -1, loc=np.mean(g.Actual), scale=st.sem(g.Actual))

Comment: also ... if my column is not normally distributed ... can I run CI on it?

Comment: Hi, I think should normalize firstly.

Comment: got it ... I've been searching around Google but can't find a direct way to normalize a column in a dataframe ... thoughts?

Comment: HI, you can use sklearn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer

Answer (score 1):

Using the [standard formula for 95% CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Assumptions_and_usage):

> `sample mean +/- 1.96 * std.err`

You can do everything in one go with `apply`:

```
def stats(g):
    r2 = r2_score(g.Actual, g.Predicted)
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(g.Actual, g.Predicted))
    ci95_hi = g.Predicted.mean() + g.Predicted.sem() * 1.96
    ci95_lo = g.Predicted.mean() - g.Predicted.sem() * 1.96
    return r2, rmse,(ci95_lo, ci95_hi)

df.groupby("Type").apply(stats)
```

Comment: the code ran!  But my ci95_hi values are all equal to my ci95_lo values...how could that be?

Comment: Not sure, they're different when I run this code with your sample data.  For example, CI for `A` is `(2.17, 19.16)`.  Are you sure you are using `+` and `-`?

Comment: ah, figured it out ... my predicted values for the same type are the same value; I did not actually run a prediction ... these values were given to me as the predictions

Comment: thank you so much for your code, I really appreciate it

Comment: given the above situation, can I run the CI on the Actual field instead?

Comment: also ... if my column is not normally distributed ... can I run CI on it?

Comment: It might help to refresh a bit on inferential statistics.  Have a look at the link in my answer for starters.  A CI is meant to help you make inferences about a sample, with respect to a true population parameter.  If `Actual` is your ground truth, a CI doesn't naturally make sense.  And it doesn't matter (usually) if your column isn't normally distributed, so long as you have enough data points for CLT to kick in. Note that it's easy to misunderstand which inferences can, in fact, be made from a CI - but that's a longer discussion you can probably learn about on CrossValidated instead of SO.